# Prevent Popup from adding padding in a column with `Arrangement.spacedBy(LARGE_PADDING)`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

So I have a Column with a Header, Body and Footer. When I replaced a Dialog in the footer with a Popup, it also applies the padding from the Arrangement to the PopupMenu. Which it did not do for the Dialog.

see problem in action
https://github.com/dessalines/jerboa/assets/67873169/6d7c4684-2355-4d1a-8072-ea7ed0044fbb

Pseudo sample

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Post() {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(LARGE_PADDING),
    ) {
        Header()
        Body()
        Footer()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Footer() {
    var showMoreOptions by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    if (showMoreOptions) {
        PostOptionsDropdown(onDismissRequest = { showMoreOptions = false }) // Just a Popup
    }

    Row {
        IconButton(onClick = { showMoreOptions = true }) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I can fix it by doing something like

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Post() {
    Column(
        // verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(LARGE_PADDING),
    ) {
        Header()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = LARGE_PADDING))
        Body()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = LARGE_PADDING))
        Footer()
    }
}
```

But I prefer finding way to make the Popup not affect the column like it does with Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's interesting. Looking at the source code of `Popup`, I can see what's causing that, but I wouldn't expect such behavior either. The thing is that while `Dialog` is always in the middle of the screen, `Popup` position is based on the place where it's used in the layout. To do that, the implementation of `Popup` uses a `Layout` with `Modifier.onGlobalyPositioned` to get the position, size and layout direction of parent layout. This adds another layout node to your column which also gets the spacing...

Best solution would be, in my opinion, to wrap the content of your `Footer` in a `Box`.